# Unable to find java console when using browser

Tags: java, google-chrome, firefox, console, icedtea

I am trying to debug an old hosted **Java Applet** but cannot find the **Java Console**.

I have tried enabling via ControlPanel

I have looked in ~/.icedtea and ~/.icedteaplugin and cannot find any `java.stderr` or `java.stdout`. In fact no new files in the last year

I am running `Ubuntu 10.04` I have tried chrome and Firefox
Chrome is Version 25.0.1364.160 Ubuntu 10.04 (25.0.1364.160-0ubuntu0.10.04.1)
FireFox is 20.0

Firefox plugin IcedTea plugin 1.2.3

`java -version gives
java version "1.6.0_27"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.12.6) (6b27-1.12.6-1ubuntu0.10.04.2)
OpenJDK Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)`

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by installing Oracle Java version 7